# need custom validation (date + particular text) in excel sheet generated using C#

Tags: c#, excel, validation

I am looking to have a validation in an excel sheet which is generated using C# such that it allows either date value or the text "train" in the excel cell. I found `XlDVType.xlValidateDate` for validating date in a cell and `XlDVType.xlValidateList` to allow text values. But I want a combination of both, user should either be able to enter date or a particular text in the cell. **Can this be accomplished using `XlDVType.xlValidateCustom` ??**

any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want a combination of both, user should either be able to enter date
>   or a particular text in the cell.

The following code snippet sets the desired validation for cell A1 in your worksheet:

```
Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.Range["A1"];
range.ClearFormats();
range.Validation.Delete();
range.Validation.Add(Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateCustom,
    Formula1: "=OR(EXACT(LEFT(CELL(\"format\",A1)),\"D\"),EXACT(A1,\"train\"))");
```

The most complicated part is the actual validation formula. It uses the following functions:

`EXACT(cell,string)` compares the contents of a cell with a literal string and returns `TRUE` only if they are exactly the same.

`CELL("format",cell)` returns a code containing the format of the indicated cell, where the code for a date always starts with a `D`. See [Office help for `CELL`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/cell-function-HP010062392.aspx) for an explanation and a list of all possible codes. This snippet only looks at the first character, which has to be a `D` in order for the contents to be formatted as some kind of date.

`LEFT(text,count)` returns the leftmost `count` characters in `text`, with `count` defaulting to 1. In this case, it returns `TRUE` if the contents are some kind of date.

`OR(logical1, logical2)` returns `logical1 OR logical2`, so `TRUE` if the contents are either a date, or exactly equal to the string `"train"`.

This solution is not yet ideal, because `A1` is hardcoded into the formula. There is a way around that using [`INDIRECT`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/indirect-function-HP010062413.aspx), described [here](http://mediaczar.com/blog/2008/12/referring-to-this-cell-using-excel-conditional-formatting/). You might need that, for example if you want to apply the validation to a whole range of cells in one go. In that case, the hardcoded `A1` needs to be replaced by `INDIRECT("RC",FALSE)`, which is the mechanism to indicate the current shell. You can read it as a short-cut for `INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE)`.

With that adjustment, he last line of code then looks like this (tested in Excel, but not from C#):

```
range.Validation.Add(Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateCustom,
    Formula1: "=OR(EXACT(LEFT(CELL(\"format\",INDIRECT(\"RC\",FALSE))),\"D\"),EXACT(INDIRECT(\"RC\",FALSE),\"train\"))"
```

---

Update

As the OP points out, there appears to be a problem with this approach if a date has first been entered into the cell, and then is changed to an incorrect string or number value -- see the comments below. Using the `CELL` function therefore does not seem to be the best approach.

However, if the cell format is explicitly set to the (more flexible) `Text` format, it is possible to impose the validation with the following lines:

```
range.Validation.Delete();
range.NumberFormat = "Text";
range.Validation.Add(Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateCustom,
    Formula1: =OR(ISNUMBER(DATEVALUE(INDIRECT(\"RC\",FALSE))),EXACT(INDIRECT(\"RC\",FALSE),\"train\"));
```

Again tested in Excel, but not from C#.

Comment: You are a genius .. thanks a ton for letting me know bout this. I actually want the solution for whole range of cells defined by `Excel.Range range` .. am unable to figure it out using your link .. can you please also help me out on this ..

Comment: Glad I could help. I have added the range-solution to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Reinier .. the formula is working weird .. it is working only on those cells that are initially empty .. it is not working on the cells that are initially not empty .. I am able to put any arbitrary value in the cells already containing the values ..

Comment: The problem here is that if the cell already has a date value in it and if I try to change to text value the cell's format is not changed. The format still is "D4" and not "G". Hence it is accepting text values as well :( .. is there an alternative to this ??

Comment: I will see if I can reproduce what you say, sometime later if I have more time...

Comment: The same issue occurred for me. There seems to be a better approach, see the update.